# Как разрезать картинку с помощью php?

Tags: php, изображения

Как можно разрезать картинку например на 16 однинаковых квадратов в виде таблицы 4х4? И вообще возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет библиотека GD2 и функция [imagecopyresized](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecopyresized.php).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Где взять эту библиотеку и как ее привинтить к апачу?

Comment: Для начала выведите phpinfo() - может она уже есть. Она сплошь и рядом используется, стандарт практически.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с изображением понадобится установленная библиотека GD. Проверить, установлена ли библиотека можно с помощью кода:

```
<?php
$gd=gd_info();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($gd);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Подробно прочитать о возможностях библиотеки GD можно тут: [работа с изображениями и библиотека GD](http://www.spravkaweb.ru/php/image/gd).

Так же можно использовать пакет [ImageMagick](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick), если позволяет хостер и ресурсы сервера. Функции нарезки изображений заметно грузят процессор и ресурсы памяти, поэтому не советую использовать их для постоянных манипуляций с изображениями. Если нужно нарезать несколько изображений лучше использовать графические редакторы.

Comment: Просто хотел сделать онлайн редактор темы для коунтер страйка для поего сайта htt://kreedz.ru/ хостер я сам себе на обычном апаче, с домашнего компа.

Спасибо! Хороший сайт! Оперативно и, самое главное, доступно. ))